# Solvability by radicals implies a radical formula for its roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, nested-radicals

I've been trying for a long time to fully understand the definition of solvability by radicals of a polynomial.
These are the two definitions I have.

**Definition 1**: We say that a field extension $F/K$ is a radical extension if we can form a chain of fields

$$K=K_0 \leq K_1 \leq \cdots \leq K_n=F$$

where $K_{i+1}/K_i$ is a simple extension such that $K_{i+1}=K_i(a_i)$ and $a_i^{k_i} \in K_i$ for some positive integer $k_i$.

**Definition 2**: Let $K$ be a field and $f(x) \in K[x]$, we say that $f$ is solvable by radicals if there exits a radical extension $F/K$ such that $F$ contains a splitting field of $f$ over $K$.

Now, I know that definition 2 formalize the concept that we can express the roots of a polynomial as some formulas that only involves the basic operations on the field over the coefficients of the polynomial (and some fixed elements of the field) and taking roots of that elements.

I can see why if we have such formulas for the roots of a polynomial we can interatively construct for every root a radical extension that contains that root, and we can then "join" them to get a radical extension that contains the spplitting field of the polynomial.

But, the reciprocal of this reasoning is what I'm not really able to see.
I can see that if we have a polynomial $f$ and it is solvable by radicals, then we have a radical extension $F/K$ containing all roots of $f$. 
Then, as we can iteratively express $F=K(a_0, \cdots, a_{n-1})$ where every $a_i$ is in a way a "nested chain of roots" of elements of $K$, we conclude that as every root of $f$ is in $F$, we can express it as sums and products of elements of $K$ and "chains" of roots of some more elements of $K$.

Now, my concrete doubt, althoug I was able to get an expresion for the roots of the polynomial in a "radical formula", the coefficients of the polynomial doesn't play any role here. Is there a way to show that every root of a solvable by radicals polynomial is expresable in the form of a "radical formula", as the ones mentioned, but involving explicitly the coefficients of the polynomial?

I've been searching for this in a lot of references but I haven't found anything that explicitely discuss this, so I'll be really greatful to anyone who can help me with this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question is unclear because $K_{i+1} = K_i( b_i^{1/k_i})$ with $b_i \in K_i$ implies $K_n = k(b_1^{1/k_1},\ldots,b_n^{1/k_n})$ where (by induction) each $b_i$ is a nested sum/product/quotient of $r$-th roots of elements of $K_0$ and that $f$ splits completely in $K_n$ means all its roots are in $K_n$ ie. they are $K$-linear combinations of powers of the $b_i^{1/k_i}$  (try with the case $n=2$ !)

Comment: Then the point is to take $L$ the normal closure of $K_n/K_0$ then  $Gal(L/K_0)$ is a solvable group. Conversely if $L/K_0$ is normal with solvable Galois group then $L$ is at the top of a tower of abelian extensions and $E/F$ abelian of degree $m$ implies $E(\zeta_m)/F(\zeta_m)$ is radical thus $E(\zeta_m)/F$ is radical and hence $L(\zeta_M)/F$ is radical.

Comment: @reuns I get that, but it is not exactly what I mean.
If $f(x)=\alpha_0+ \alpha_1x+\cdots+\alpha_mx^m$ and we have that its splitting field is contained on $K({b_1}^{1/k_1}, \cdots, {b_n}^{1/k_n})$, I know we can express the roots as some combinations of sums, and products of elements of $K$ and the ${b_i}^{k_i}$, but my point is that the coefficients of the polynomial doesn't appear in that expression and I was wondering if we can prove that such a formula involving the coefficients exists for every root if the polynomial is solvable.

Comment: @reuns But, I don't see why in the complicated expression involving nested radicals, is in terms of the coefficients of $f$. 
I mean, Iknow the roots are in terms of the $b_i$, but these are not necessarely the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: The radical formulas for the roots depend on constants of $K$, once the polynomial is fixed this is all we want (there are algorithms for the splitting field minimal polynomials and Galois group, if it is solvable we can unroll to find the radical formulas). What you are asking is if there are finitely many radical formulas $F_{d,l}$ of $d+1$ variables such that for every solvable polynomial $\sum_{j=0}^d c_j x^j\in K[x]$ of degree $d$ its roots are given by $F_{d,l}(c_0,\ldots,c_d)$ for some $l$. This is the problem of moduli space / parametrization of solvable polynomials of degree $d$.

Comment: Okay, I think now I get it. Thank you very much!